# Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported Types: int + string

Tags: php

Im practicing php for my project purpose. Im trying for arithmatic operation in php. The exact operation was the value will be altered manually by user. the manual enter value should be check with existing database and subtract the value and make addition arithmatic operation to the the other sql table. here the code.

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
$qty=$_POST["qty"];
$inwno=$_POST["inwno"];
$idprodin=$_POST["idprodin"];
    

$cal= "Select bill.dc.qty From bill.dc where id =".$id;
$val =$con-> query($cal);
$res= $val->fetch_array()[0]??'';


$cal1= "Select bill.dc.inwno From bill.dc where id =".$inwno;
$val1 =$con-> query($cal1);
$res1= $val1->fetch_array()[0]??'';


$sub = ($res - $qty) + $res1 ;

$sql1= "UPDATE `inward_prod` SET `prodqty`= $sub WHERE idinpro=".$idprodin;
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);


$sql= "UPDATE `dc` SET `qty`='{$_POST["qty"]}' WHERE id=".$_POST["id"];
$sql2= "UPDATE `dcinfo` SET `dcdate`='$dcdate' WHERE iddcinfo=".$idinfo;


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have [strict types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.strict) enabled in your PHP settings. That error message can be reproduced with [the following code](https://3v4l.org/fE3G3):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int + string
0 + "";
```

---

In your code specifically, this is probably occurring on this line:

```
$sub = ($res - $qty) + $res1 ;
```

The error indicates that `$res1` is a string. You should check that value to ensure that it is an integer. If it's a numeric string, you could type cast it to an integer `$sub = ($res - $qty) + ((int) $res1);`. However, you might want to review that your SQL query, `"Select bill.dc.inwno From bill.dc where id =".$inwno;`,  is returning the intended results and set a more appropriate default when it returns an unexpected result: `$res1 = $val1->fetch_array()[0] ?? 0;`.

Comment: I have tries to type cast the $sub = ($res - $qty) + ((int) $res1); its passing the operation and updating the value in $result but not updating in the $sql query.